# Nested column chart with drilldown

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of `salary`ies for employees. Each salary consist of a date and what contributed to it (bonuses, hourly wage, adjustments...).

I want to display the `salary`ies in a simple `column` highchart, where the series is split by month and hence salaries from a given month are stacked up. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d1j7ongL/

What I want to have is a drilldown, such that when a month is clicked, all employees get displayed along with a breakdown of each salary by stack column (bonuses, hourly wage...), like this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/gpu2oL1t/

The problem is that I cannot get it to work. The closest I got was so group the data by category (ie. bonuses together, hourly salaries together etc):
http://jsfiddle.net/9tog4rkm/

The only problem is that I want the drill down data transposed (?). 'columns should be rows, rows should be columns' in a sense. I don't want to see the breakdown per category, but rather per employee.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create five `drilldown` series with names: `'Salary', 'Points', 'Adjustments', 'Bonuses', 'Foodstamps'` and the names of employees as point names.

Example:

```
"drilldown": {
    series: [{
        name: 'Salary',
        id: "employee-01",
        data: [[
            "employee-0",
            328
        ], [
            "employee-1",
            52
        ]]
    }, {    
        name: 'Points',
        id: "employee-11",
        data: [[
            "employee-0",
            -291
        ], [
            "employee-1",
            52
        ]]
    }, {
        name: 'Adjustments',
        id: "employee-131",
        data: [[
            "employee-0",
            -9
        ], [
            "employee-1",
            148
        ]]
    }, {
        name: 'Bonuses',
        id: "employee-201",
        data: [[
            "employee-0",
            0
        ], [
            "employee-1",
            0
        ]]
    }, {
        name: 'Foodstamps',
        id: "employee-81",
        data: [[
            "employee-0",
            0
        ], [
            "employee-1",
            0
        ]]
    }]
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dmqfwejz/